# Почему each не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Код

```
var datas=[];     
datas[pole]=text;
        $.each(datas, function (key, value) {
            alert(key+":"+value);
        });
```

по чему-то алерт не выводится консоль тоже молчит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причина в том что вы объявили массив и пытаетесь с ним работать как с объектом, если объявить объект, то всё работает:

```js
var datas={};     
datas['pole']='text';
$.each(datas, function (key, value) {
  alert(key+":"+value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```